# Age replacement policy for hard disks and SSDs at servers

Tags: hard-drive, ssd, drive-failure

I'm planing an age replacement policy for our storage and servers. Most of them are for DBs and some for images (static content) so yes, they have an huge I/O everytime.

Also, we use Samsung 840 Pro SSDs for the RAID Controllers (PERC H700i) as CacheCade.

Are you guys managing the replacement of old hard drives and solid state drives?

Comment: When they fail or begin exhibiting the symptoms of impending failure they get replaced. I've never heard of anyone proactively replacing hard drives based on age.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

We don't proactively replace disks.

Wait until they fail or report prefailure status. This is why you have (hardware) RAID, management agents, failure indication LEDs on the server and a monitoring solution.

Keeping your gear under warranty and maintain your support contracts (within reason), having cold spares of components that fail often (disks, power supplies, RAM) and proactively *monitoring* the environment will take you much farther.

Comment: Hmm. RAM fails often? The RAM that's good from the start (no memtest errors) seems to hold out forever for me.

Comment: @Halfgaar In larger environments and at large enough scale, RAM fails... No way to prevent it.

Comment: Yeap, RAM fails sometimes :( Power supply fails are easy to avoid when you have redundant power

Answer (score 3):

We don't proactively replace disks either.  Backblaze recently did a [blog post](http://blog.backblaze.com/2013/11/12/how-long-do-disk-drives-last/) on this subject.  One should note that they primarily use consumer grade drives.